# Date datatype in SQL Server gets changed to nvarchar datatype in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am importing a SQL Server table into Informatica as a source. One of the column's datatype in the SQL Server table is `DATE`.

When I import it, its showing up as `nvarchar` in Informatica.

Can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide more details? Here's a quick test I've done:

- I've created a sample table on SQL Server 11 with date, datetime and smalldatetime columns:

[image: Sample datetime table]

- Imported it as Source to Informatica 9.5.1:
  [image]

As you can see, all looks pretty good. Let me know what can I do to replicate the issue. Or simply alter the imported source to reflect the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

I have a table (in SQL Server DB ) with columns defined as 'date'. When I imported, they converted to 'nvarchar (10)'. however, I have another column defined as 'datetime', which imported as datetime properly.
Looks there is an issue with 'date' defined column.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be because of a particular driver you are using to import the table. I haven't tried it any time with SQL Server however have seen this issue with Oracle table imports.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I have to import the table through "DataDirect 7.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol"

[image: DataDirect 7.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol]